# Missing titles for the outer grids in a nested gridspec using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to visualize all the attention heads together with a batch of source and target sequence (both of them are 2D arrays) in a transformer. I am following existing examples to make a nested gridspec. But existing [examples](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/demo_constrained_layout.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-demo-constrained-layout-py) only show how to put titles on the inner grids. But none of them shows how to put the title in the outer grid.

This is the closest result I can get

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

predictions = {}
predictions['attention'] = np.random.randn(4, 2, 5, 5)
predictions['frame'] = np.zeros((4, 2, 5, 2))
mel = np.ones((4, 2, 2, 5))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))
# Creating the grid for 2 attention head for the transformer
outer = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
fig.suptitle("Visualizing Attention Heads", size=20)

for i in range(2):
    # Creating the grid for 4 samples
    inner = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 2,
                    subplot_spec=outer[i], wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)
    ax = plt.Subplot(fig, outer[i])
    ax.set_title(f'Head {i}', size=20) # This does not show up
    for idx in range(4):
        axCenter = plt.Subplot(fig, inner[idx])
        fig.add_subplot(axCenter)
        attentions = predictions['attention'][idx, i]
        axCenter.imshow(attentions, cmap='jet', vmin=0, vmax=0.7)
        

        attended_features = mel[idx, i]

        # Create another plot on top and left of the attention map
        divider = make_axes_locatable(axCenter)
        axvert = divider.append_axes('left', size='30%', pad=0.5)
        axhoriz = divider.append_axes('top', size='20%', pad=0.25)
        axhoriz.imshow(attended_features, aspect='auto', origin='lower', cmap='jet')
        axvert.imshow(predictions['frame'][idx, i], aspect='auto')

        # changing axis for the center fig
        axCenter.set_xticks([])

        # changing axis for the output fig (left fig)
        axvert.set_yticks([])
        axvert.xaxis.tick_top()
        axvert.set_title('Transcription')

        axhoriz.set_title(f'Attended Feature (Spec)')

        axhoriz.margins(x=0)
        axvert.margins(y=0)
```

And the figure produced is like this:

[image]

As you can see, the big title for the whole plot and the titles for the inner grids are all there. But the titles for the outer grids are nowhere to be found (as indicated by the red circle). How to make the titles for outer grids appear?

Comment: I think you forgot to add `ax` Axes to the figure. Your original code works if you simply add 
 `fig.add_subplot(ax)` just before you set the title. Maybe a statement to get rid of the spines (`ax.axis(False)`) will also be required. However, this will give you title at only the top two positions. You might need to rearrange your Gridspec to get this at all four locations

Comment: Any hint on how to rearrange? I don't think I can change the two for loops, since the first for loop is for the batch dimension, and the second for loop is for the attention heads. Given the existing loop structure, there is very limited places that I can change.

Comment: It might need a bit of debugging on my part, but if all you want is text at those locations, you can manually put that using `ax.text()`. I admit this isn't the most convenient way, but it will work quite well.